# How to add `redux-logger` on middlewares?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to add `redux-logger` on the middlewares chain. Below is my code:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import reducers from './index';

import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const logger = createLogger ({
  log: 'info',
});
// create the global store
const store = compose (applyMiddleware (thunk, logger)) (createStore) (
  reducers
);

export default store;
```

I will get below error with above code:

```
applyMiddleware.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function
    at applyMiddleware.js:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at applyMiddleware.js:38
```

It works fine if I change the apply middleware to this line:

```
applyMiddleware (thunk, createLogger)
```

but I need to create the logger with some specific parameters. How can I add the created logger into middleware chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';

const composeEnhancers = typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({}) : compose;

const middlewareList = [thunk, logger]

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewareList)
);

const store = createStore(reducers, enhancer);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should working fine if you change your store into this:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)));
```

If that doesn't work, take a look into this issue. It should do the same as above code I think.

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by changing the `import` to `import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';`.